# "Can't Set Headers..." Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

The following is the code to an api I'm working on where the client sends a short video file to express and express uploads it to cloudinary. The api successfully uploads a video to cloudinary the first time /routes/upload is called. Things start to get funny when the route is called a second time. The video is still successfully uploaded to cloudinary BUT I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong because I do have other routes that use `res.json` and when I call them multiple times I don't get an error at all. How can I address this issue?

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('express-formidable');
var app = express();

app.use(formidable());

var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/routes', routes);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Express server is listening on port ' + port);
});
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cloudinary = require('../cloudinary.js').cloudinary;
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
  var fileGettingUploaded = req.files.fileToUpload.path;

  cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileGettingUploaded, function(result) {
    res.json(result);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

cloudinary.js

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: 'name',
  api_key: 'key',
  api_secret: 'secret'
});

module.exports.cloudinary = cloudinary;
```

Full error

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:164:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:250:15)
    at /Users/myname/appdirectory/app.js:82:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
    at /Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /Users/myname/appdirectory/app.js:76:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at form.parse (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/express-formidable/lib/middleware.js:17:7)
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:105:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (/Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:553:8)
    at /Users/myname/appdirectory/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:230:12
```

Comment: What are the values of `fileGettingUploaded` and `result ` before `res.json(result);`?  Add a `console.log(fileGettingUploaded, result);` if you don't have a debugger.  The [cloudinary uploader](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/src/uploader.coffee#L196) looks like it's could possibly run the callback multiple times.

Comment: @Matt The app returns the error message THEN logs fileGettingUploaded and result

Comment: I'm guessing you're not showing the entirety of app.js because the stack trace is referencing much larger line numbers. Especially of interest is line 82, which is apparently where a second `res.json()` is occurring...